# Are there any programming languages in which int() rounds (rather than truncates)?

Tags: casting, integer, rounding

I was recently involved in a discussion about the use of pseudocode in Computer Science exams.  There was a question that used integer division.  I said that *a DIV b* is the same as *INT(a / b)*, but another contributor said that the effect of INT() depended on the implementation of the language and it could sometimes round up.

My understanding (and 36 years' experience) is that int() always truncates - i.e. rounds down.  Are you aware of any programming languages in which this is not the case by design, e.g. would int(1.7) ever give 2?

Comment: Since you cannot always exactly represent a decimal number in binary form, `int()` _could_ sometimes round up in some languages. For example in Python `int(2.9999999999999999)` gives you 3. However `int(2.999999999999999)` (one 9 less) gives you 2.

Comment: Thanks - that's an interesting example.  I suppose I meant "by design", rather than by representational quirk!

Comment: @Psytho: The `int` call there is irrelevant: `2.9999999999999999` is *already* exactly equal to `3.0`, so the argument that `int` receives is exactly `3.0`, and `int` returns exactly the same value. Python's `int` (currently) *never* rounds away from zero.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this question could be formally answered for the simple reason that on any give day a developer may come out with a <strike>hipster</strike>cool new language where `int` rounds instead of truncating.

Having said that, in any common programming language I've ever used or even heard about, `int` truncates. To be on the safe side, when designing such a question, you could just explicitly state what `int` means in its context. E.g.:

> `int(x)` means that `x` is truncated to the closest integer value not greater than `x`. E.g., `int(1.7)` will return `1`.

Comment: Thanks.  You're right - it was a sloppy question and I've now reworded it slightly!